# ¿ Cómo recorrer tablas fila por fila y obtener todos los valores de los elementos?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

acudo por ayuda debido a que tengo problemas para obtener los valores de una tabla.ya que la tabla tiene elementos como input y select...
Bueno lo que quiero hacer es que me obtenga todos los valores de dicha tabla, en cuanto a input ya me obtiene pero en cuanto a un select aun sigo teniendo problemas y de la misma forma que cada vez que hago un click en el botón "recorrer" no duplique los datos en otras filas como se puede ver en el script..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn-new").on('click', function() {
    var html = '<tr>' +
      '<td class="numero"><input type="text" class="form-control txt" onkeyup=""></td>' +
      '<td class="numero">' +
      '<select name="md" class="form-control sele" id="">' +
      '<option value="0">Seleccionar...</option>' +
      '<option value="1">Kilos</option>' +
      '<option value="2">Metros</option>' +
      '</select>' +
      '</td>' +
      '<td class="numero">' +
      '<select name="ds" class="form-control sele2" id="">' +
      '<option value="0">Seleccionar...</option>' +
      '<option value="1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</option>' +
      '<option value="2">Descripcion numero 02.</option>' +
      '</select>' +
      '</td>' +
      '<td class="numero"><input type="text" class="form-control txt" onkeyup=""></td>' +
      '<td class="numero"><input type="text" class="form-control txt" onkeyup=""></td>' +
      '<td class="boton"><a type="button" class="btn btn-info">Eliminar</a></td>' +
      '</tr>';
    $("#tbody").append(html);
  });
  $("#btnRecorrer").on("click", function() {
    var sele = $(".sele option:selected").text();
    var sele2 = $(".sele2 option:selected").text();
    alert(sele + '\n' + " * " + sele2 + '\n');
    $("#tabla tbody tr").each(function(index) {
      var campo1, campo2, campo3, campo4, campo5;
      $(this).find("td input.txt").each(function(index2) {
        switch (index2) {
          case 0:
            campo1 = $(this).val();
            break;
          case 1:
            campo2 = $(this).val();
            break;
          case 2:
            campo3 = $(this).val();
            break;
          case 3:
            campo4 = $(this).val();
            break;
          case 4:
            campo5 = $(this).val();
            break;
        }
      });
      var html = '<tr>' +
        '<td>' + campo1 + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + campo2 + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + campo3 + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + campo4 + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + campo5 + '</td>' +
        '</tr>';
      $("#body").append(html);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Ventas C.I.</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <br><br><br>
  <div class="container">
    <button id="btn-new" class="btn btn-success">Agregar Nuevo</button>
    <br><br>
    <center>

      <table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="tabla">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>CANTIDAD</th>
            <th>MEDIDA</th>
            <th>DESCRIPCION</th>
            <th>PRECIO</th>
            <th>TOTAL</th>
            <th>OPCION</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tbody">

        </tbody>
      </table><br><br>
      <button id="btnRecorrer" class="btn btn-primary pull-left">Recorrer</button><br><br>
      <table class="table table-hover table-bordered" border="1" id="tbl">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Valor 1</th>
            <th>Valor 2</th>
            <th>Valor 3</th>
            <th>Valor 4</th>
            <th>Valor 5</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="body">
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </center>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Es porque aquí `find("td input.txt")` solo estás agarrando los input de tipo text, si quieres que te elija los `select` y `text` puedes hacerlo con `find("input, select")` o para todos los tipos de input con `find(":input")`.

Tu código con el segundo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn-new").on('click', function() {
    var html = '<tr>' +
      '<td class="numero"><input type="text" class="form-control txt" onkeyup=""></td>' +
      '<td class="numero">' +
      '<select name="md" class="form-control sele" id="">' +
      '<option value="0">Seleccionar...</option>' +
      '<option value="1">Kilos</option>' +
      '<option value="2">Metros</option>' +
      '</select>' +
      '</td>' +
      '<td class="numero">' +
      '<select name="ds" class="form-control sele2" id="">' +
      '<option value="0">Seleccionar...</option>' +
      '<option value="1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</option>' +
      '<option value="2">Descripcion numero 02.</option>' +
      '</select>' +
      '</td>' +
      '<td class="numero"><input type="text" class="form-control txt" onkeyup=""></td>' +
      '<td class="numero"><input type="text" class="form-control txt" onkeyup=""></td>' +
      '<td class="boton"><a type="button" class="btn btn-info">Eliminar</a></td>' +
      '</tr>';
    $("#tbody").append(html);
  });
  $("#btnRecorrer").on("click", function() {
    $("#body").html(""); // Limpiamos la tabla para que no se dupliquen los datos
    $("#tabla tbody tr").each(function(index) {
      var campo1, campo2, campo3, campo4, campo5;
      $(this).find(":input").each(function(index2) {
        switch (index2) {
          case 0:
            campo1 = $(this).val();
            break;
          case 1:
            campo2 = $(this).val();
            break;
          case 2:
            campo3 = $(this).val();
            break;
          case 3:
            campo4 = $(this).val();
            break;
          case 4:
            campo5 = $(this).val();
            break;
        }
      });
      var html = '<tr>' +
        '<td>' + campo1 + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + campo2 + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + campo3 + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + campo4 + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + campo5 + '</td>' +
        '</tr>';
      $("#body").append(html);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <button id="btn-new" class="btn btn-success">Agregar Nuevo</button>
  <br><br>
  <center>

    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="tabla">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>CANTIDAD</th>
          <th>MEDIDA</th>
          <th>DESCRIPCION</th>
          <th>PRECIO</th>
          <th>TOTAL</th>
          <th>OPCION</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="tbody">

      </tbody>
    </table><br><br>
    <button id="btnRecorrer" class="btn btn-primary pull-left">Recorrer</button><br><br>
    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered" border="1" id="tbl">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Valor 1</th>
          <th>Valor 2</th>
          <th>Valor 3</th>
          <th>Valor 4</th>
          <th>Valor 5</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="body">
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </center>
</div>
```

Comment: excelente gracias por la respuesta tengo otra duda aun, caso que cuando hago click dos a mas veces me agrega los datos en otros tr debajo del que ya existe, como podria evitar eso ? y que solo actualice los datos que ya existe en las mismas filas si en caso que se hizo algun cambio en las filas... y de igual manera no me obtiene los valores seleccionados del select

Comment: @Efrain no me fijé en lo de no duplicar, una solución sencilla sería limpiar la tabla de resultados cada vez que se de click en recorrer y copiar la tabla principal tal como está. En un momento edito la respuesta. En cuanto a los select, si obtiene sus valores, o tu necesitas el texto que se despliega en el select?

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder pero ya solucioné solo elimino los datos que ya existe y remplazo con los valores nuevos.

Comment: Puse una solución similar jaja, Si la respuesta solucionó el problema puedes marcarla como aceptada, si por otro lado lo solucionaste de una manera distinta puedes poner tu respuesta por si alguien se encuentra con un problema similar :)